# setting max date value to oracle 10g from sql2000+n

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle10g

Hi
I have this update statement

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(linkedServerToOracle ,"SELECT   T$TDAT FROM BAAN.TTDSLS031010 WHERE T$CUNO='003098' AND T$CPGS=' 4AN00'") 
SET T$TDAT=CONVERT(varchar, '4712-01-01 00:00', 121)
```

and 
the current setting in linkedServerToOracle (10g) is supposed to take the value '4712-01-01 00:00' as pseudo infinite date time
i.e Applications supposed to render this value blank (eg BaaN 4c )..
but it does not do that when I update the column in question through linkedServer..
Any help is appriciated..
Thanks

Comment: if you truly want the value blank, can you not set it to `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently setting a date to Julian 0 seconds  as following do the trick..

```
Update baan.ttipcs530070 set t$pddt=to_date('1 0','J SSSSS')
```